# for loop in tkMessageBox.showinfo in Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to implement a `for` loop in the `Tkinter` tkMessageBox.showinfo() in python
I need to print a `list of lists` in the box.

What I currently have is:

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo(
    "Help INFORMATION",
    "help1 help2 \n help3 help4 \n help5 help6"
    )
```

What I want is:
Something like below..

```
my_list=[['help1','help2'],['help3','help4'],['help5','help6']]

tkMessageBox.showinfo(
        "Help INFORMATION",
        for i in my_list:
            i + "\n" #cant use print as I want to display it in the dialog box and not in the console. 

        )
```

So that the output in the dialog box should be like this :

```
help1 help2
help3 help4
help5 help6
```

But what I get is:

```
Syntax Error -> for i in my_list:
```

Comment: you just want the list to be flattened ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElkady Edited the question see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
    my_list=[['help1','help2'],['help3','help4'],['help5','help6']]
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(
        "Help INFORMATION",
        '\n'.join(map(' '.join, my_list))
    )
```

I did not test it but should ideally do the job.

Comment: @A_nagpal Yup , This is the **better** approach that I missed

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: Are you sure? I don't have tKinter with me atm, but type('\n'.join(map(' '.join, my_list))) does return string.

Comment: Oops! I made a silly mistake! Your answer is absolutely fine! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok you can try this , I know it's not the most efficient one but it works !

```
my_list=[['help1','help2'],['help3','help4'],['help5','help6']]


def to_tuples(list):
    tuples = []
    for sublist in list :
        tuples.append(tuple(sublist))
    return tuples


def dialog_info(tuples):
    res = ""
    for element in tuples :
        res += ' '.join(element)
        res += '\n'

    return res

print dialog_info(my_list)
```

now you can just use :

```
my_list = [['help1', 'help2'], ['help3', 'help4'], ['help5', 'help6']]

tkMessageBox.showinfo(
    "Help INFORMATION",
    dialog_info(my_list)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
'\n'.join(map(' '.join, my_list))
```

instead of the for loop.